# Oracle 19c database silent installation {FATAL] [INS-35954] error

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

Hi I am trying to install Oracle 19c database using response file and silent installation. Previously when I had oracle 12c my ORACLE_HOME was set to any directory I wanted i.e. "D:\Oracle12c\product\dbhome_1" now when trying to perform similar action but in 19c Im facing below error: {FATAL] [INS-35954] The installer has detected that the Oracle home location provided in the response file is not correct. Any ideas? I am on windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Frank Pachot](https://blog.dbi-services.com/author/franckpachot/) has a
solution in
[18c runInstaller -silent](https://blog.dbi-services.com/18c-runinstaller-silent/):

> You find two different ‘runInstaller’ under an Oracle Home. The old one, the
> Oracle Universal Installer, in $ORACLE_HOME/oui/bin. And the new one, in
> $ORACLE_HOME directly. They have the same name but are completely different.
> The old one was used to install an Oracle Home from the installation media.
> But in 18c you don’t use it. It has been used by Oracle to build the Oracle
> Home image. Then you download and unzip directly your Oracle Home. You have
> only to configure it and re-link the binaries. And this is done by the new
> runInstaller which is at the root of the Oracle Home.

The solution would be something like:

```
mkdir %ORACLE_HOME%
```

unzip download.zip into the ORACLE_HOME directory

```
cd %ORACLE_HOME%
runInstaller
```

The change directory is important!